# Google Drive API: Download file gives lockedDomainCreationFailure error

Tags: javascript, oauth-2.0, google-api, google-drive-api, google-drive-picker

I'm trying to download a file with the Google Drive File Picker (based upon this example https://gist.github.com/Daniel15/5994054). The File Picker works fine up to the point where it comes to download a file. It runs into a 400 Bad-Request (lockedDomainCreationFailure) error.

Here's the code:

```js
function downloadFile(file, callback) {
  if (file.downloadUrl) {
    var accessToken = gapi.auth.getToken().access_token;
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('GET', file.downloadUrl);
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + accessToken);
    xhr.onload = function() {
      callback(xhr.responseText);
    };
    xhr.onerror = function() {
      callback(null);
    };
    xhr.send();
  } else {
    callback(null);
  }
}
```

Here's the error message:

```json
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "lockedDomainCreationFailure",
    "message": "The OAuth token was received in the query string, which this API forbids for response formats other than JSON or XML. If possible, try sending the OAuth token in the Authorization header instead."
   }
  ],
  "code": 400,
  "message": "The OAuth token was received in the query string, which this API forbids for response formats other than JSON or XML. If possible, try sending the OAuth token in the Authorization header instead."
 }
}
```

It tells that to OAuth token was given in the query string, which as I see is not true.
Here's the request:

```
GET /drive/v2/files/{file-id}?key={app-key}&alt=media&source=downloadUrl HTTP/3
Host: content.googleapis.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:89.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/89.0
Accept: */*
Accept-Language: en,de;q=0.7,en-US;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Authorization: Bearer {oauth-token}
Origin: http://localhost:8800
DNT: 1
Connection: keep-alive
Referer: http://localhost:8800/
TE: Trailers
```

Since I'm using the download url provided by to Google API and the authorization is given in the request header, i've got no clue why I run into this error.

I appreciate any ideas.

Comment: See if changing the request url to `  'https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/[FILEID]?key=[YOUR_API_KEY] HTTP/1.1` as well as specifying `Accept: application/json` solves the issue. Also: what is `{app-id}`?

Comment: By "app-id" I mean the application key. I corected that in my OP.
The **solution** was not to query `content.googleapis.com` but `www.googleapis.com`. Thanks for that hint! I don't know why, because what comes out as download URL from the Google API is the first host name.
Changing the "Accept" header was not neccesarry. The request URL must contain `alt` and `source` query parametes, otherwise you get file meta data only, but not its content.
So the download url is `https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/{file-id}?key={app-key}&alt=media&source=downloadUrl`.
Again, thank you vey much.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The solution was to change the host `content.googleapis.com` (what was provided as download url from the Google API) to `www.googleapis.com`. Thanks [ziganotschka](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11599789/ziganotschka) for that hint!

So the correct download url is `https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/{file-id}?key={app-key}&alt=media&source=downloadUrl`. It  must contain "alt" and "source" query parametes, otherwise you get file meta data only, but not its content. No need to change the "Accept" header.

Answer (score 0):

**#Update For Google Drive Api Version 3**

`https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/{file-id}?key={APIKey}&alt=media&source=downloadUrl`

How To Get/Create API Key >
https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials